# Can't use jar library in my java file

Tags: java

Sorry for this noobie question, I'm new to Java, and instead of using IDE, i want to using command line to learn what's running under the hood

I'm following the Getting Started guild on [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com)

```
#MigWindow.java

public class MigWindow {
    public static void main(){
        javax.swing.JPanel panel = new javax.swing.JPanel(new MigLayout());// a simple line to make sure the library jar import correctly 
        
    }

}
```

and compile with these command:

```
javac -cp ./MigLayout.jar MigWindow.java
```

and I got a error:

```
MigWindow.java:3: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class MigLayout
location: class MigWindow
        javax.swing.JPanel panel = new javax.swing.JPanel(new MigLayout());
        

                                                      ^
1 error
```

It seems the jar library doesn't import correctly, any idea?

~

Comment: Where are the files MigWindow.java and MigLayout.jar?  What is the default directory of the command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you add the import for `MigLayout`

```
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;
```

It may sound obvious, but make sure `MigLayout.jar` the current directory when calling `javac` here and that your JAR file has not been corrupted.

**Update:**

To check that your JAR file *does* contain the class you can do:

```
jar tvf MigLayout.jar
```

and check for the `MigLayout` class. Failing to find the class you can download the correct one from [here](http://www.miglayout.com/).

Comment: How can I tell the full package name "net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout" form Jar file?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/miginfocom/swing/MigLayout

Comment: It's possible that the JAR file doesn't contain the `MigLayout` class. See update

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an import statement in your Source File. The compiler does not know where 'MigLayout' is coming from.

Add at the top of your file, but below of your `package` statement (if any) an import, e.g.

```
import package.MigLayout;
```

This tells the compiler what to import from the given class path. You will need to replace `package` with the correct package.